Traveling back to Sweden while waiting for the acceptance of the Residence Card (Carta di Sioggiorno) in Italy
I am Swedish and my husband is Argentinian, we are living in Italy because I got a job here some months ago, and with my husband we will apply for the Residence Card (Carta di Sioggiorno) in Italy. The tourist Visa of my husband expired a couple of weeks ago but the poilice said that he can stay as long as we have the Questura (Central Police) certificate that we booked a time to apply for the Residence Card.
We are wondering if we can come back to Sweden and wait for the decision there after applying for the Residence Card, in case we do not receive the decision before my working contract expires in 3 months here in Italy.
Thank you so much!

Argentines do not require a visa for the Schengen Area, so I assume you mean the entry stamp (which is used to enforce the 90/180 day rule). When traveling with (or joining) the EU citizen spouse, the 90/180 day rule does not apply.
